# ULONG to qint Qt c++

Tags: c++, qt

My problem is very simple. I have a `ULONG` variable that I need to convert to a `qint` of some sort. I haven't found anything referring to how to do so on the internet.

What I am trying to do is download a file and forward the progress to my `QWebView` object through `evaluateJavascript()`. I use `IBindStatusCallback` to get the progress of the file downloaded.

Comment: Doesn't `static_cast<quintNN>(ulongVar)` work?

Comment: Care, it's a possible loss of precision

Comment: It work, isn't really super important that there is no loss since I'm only using it to display progress.